# ¿Es un sustantivo propio un sustantivo individual?

Tags: definiciones

Por definición, los sustantivos *propios* identifican un ser entre otros de la misma clase sin informar de sus cualidades (Pedro, España) y los sustantivos *individuales* denotan personas, animales o cosas que concebimos como entidades únicas (perro, oveja, libro). Así que, ¿Es un sustantivo *propio*, a su vez, uno *individual*?

Para ello, consideremos un sustantivo *individual* como lo es *profesor*. ¿Es el sustantivo único en su clase? No, pues *profesor* hace referencia a una clase, no a un ejemplar. Sin embargo, según [wikilengua](https://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Sustantivo#:%7E:text=El%20sustantivo%20propio%20o%20nombre,propios%20se%20consideran%20sustantivos%20individuales.) esto no es cierto, pero creo que se equivoca. Es más, según la RAE,  los sustantivos comunes se pueden clasifcar en *contables, no contables, individuales, colectivos, abstractos* y *concretos* por lo que un sustantivo *individual* es uno *común*.

Comment: @Lambie ¿A qué te refieres con "No creo que un sustantivo propio como Pedro pueda pertenecer a dos categorias"?

Comment: @Lambie Sí, por supuesto. Sin embargo, como es propio, es común.

Comment: @Lambie Cierto, ya me di cuenta.

Answer (score 2):

El sustantivo propio es, por definición, "individual". Esto no quita que no pueda usarse en plural o asemejarse a un sustantivo común:

1. Por referirse a un conjunto de objetos: los Alpes, los Pirineos, los Andes (nombres de cordilleras)
2. Por usarse con numerales como si fueran sustantivos comunes:

- Tengo dos Picassos (= dos cuadros pintados por Picasso) en mi colección.
- Hay dos Españas: una antes y otra después de Franco.
- Espero una Argentina diferente.
- Se compró tres Audis (tres autos marca Audi).

3. Por usarse con artículos, posesivos y calificativos:

- No es el mismo Pedro que yo conocí.
- ¿De quién estás enamorado: de la María modelo o de la María ama de casa?
- Su circunspecto Dr. Jekyll a veces cede frente a su Sr. Hyde interior.